# Sending email with VMIME/libcurl not through a server (or: SMTP server library)

Tags: c++, c, email, curl, smtp

I have seen many tutorials (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-multi.html, VMIME website, etc) that explain how to send mail through some server like GMail or whatever. That is, they require a username/password to log in to some server, and then they forward the email through the server to the destination.

What I am looking for and cannot find is an explanation of how to send email that is not routed through a server though. How do you send email without a mail server? I am looking for a [Linux] library that can let my program be the mail server itself, both to send mail and receive it. If this is not possible with curl or vmime then I will be glad to switch to another library. I really do not want to have to roll my own SMTP server, but I've spent a day on google to no avail, and read the VMIME book but I can't find anything helpful and it's a little abstruse to my mind.

**Edit**:

So basically I'm looking for a SMTP server library (that can also send emails to other servers) for C or C++. Does such a thing exist? I see them for .NET and Java and Python but no C or C++ yet. Still googling...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't know of any that are still active.  VMIME has some support but the API for SMTP/SMTPS is kinda awkward looking.  I have looked at libcurl for the sending portion too.  It looks a bit easier to manage than VMIME's SMTP/SMTPS API.  I am currently using VMIME to generate the messages and am sending using the MSMTP utility.  The combination of VMIME and MSMTP works great but would prefer to keep it all in one utility program...